# How to dump all (X, Y) positions of UIElements in a WPF Grid

Tags: wpf, layout, position, uielement

I would like to know how to iterate through all the elements in a WPF `Grid`, and then access the absolute positioning values (X, Y) for all of these `UIElements`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (UIElement child in grid.Children)
{
    MatrixTransform t = (MatrixTransform)child.TransformToAncestor(grid);
    Point childLocation = new Point(t.Value.OffsetX, t.Value.OffsetY);
}
```

Will give you the coordinates of all the direct children relative to the `Grid`.